# how to plot heatmap with 4 variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPD5l.png)I want to plot heatmap with 4 continuous variable in R. What I want is size of square shape in heatmap should change according to 4th continuous variable

[image]

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and what particular problems you are getting.

Comment: Changing square size in a heatmap sounds like a bad idea. What do you envisage the final result to look like? Also consider showing some code & making your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to get more targeted help.

Comment: I want final result look like as shown below. I want to plot mean values. hewre they have taken 5 variables where as it is only 4. I was trying ggplot + stat-summary_2d. But it takes only 3 variables